# Slicing a box IE7 spacing problem

Tags: css, slice

I'm trying to slice an box with rounded corners. The image is sliced horizontal in 3parts (top-middle-bottom). The problem in IE7 is that the top div is larger than the actual size I set.

Here is the HTML & CSS code

```
<!-- FIRST PICTURE -->
  <div class='recent-box'>
    <div class='recent-box-top'></div>
    <div class='recent-box-middle' >                            
    </div>
    <div class='recent-box-bottom'></div>     
   </div>
   <!-- FIRST PICTURE -->
  <div class='recent-box'>
    <div class='recent-box-top'></div>
    <div class='recent-box-middle'>

    </div>
    <div class='recent-box-bottom'></div>     
   </div>
   <!-- FIRST PICTURE -->
  <div class='recent-box'>
    <div class='recent-box-top'></div>
    <div class='recent-box-middle'>
    dsqd
    </div>
    <div class='recent-box-bottom'></div>     
   </div>
   <!-- FIRST PICTURE -->
  <div class='recent-box'>
    <div class='recent-box-top'></div>
    <div class='recent-box-middle'>
    dsqd
    </div>
    <div class='recent-box-bottom'></div>     
   </div>


    .recent-box {
    width: 127px;
    float:left;
 display:block;
}

.recent-box-top {
    float:left;
    background-image: url('images/recent-foto-top.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width: 100%;

}

.recent-box-middle {
    float:left;    
    background-image: url('images/recent-foto-middle.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-y; 
    width: 100%;

}

.recent-box-bottom {
    float:left;    
    background-image: url('images/recent-foto-bottom.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 
    width: 100%;

}
```

Thanks for helping me out!
Ward

Answer (score 0):

The `font-size` and `line-height` properties might be the offensive ones. If you are not placing any text in the top box, use something like

```
.recent-box-top {
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!

Just put  in the div and it works like a charm!

found on http://archivist.incutio.com/viewlist/css-discuss/39150